# Laravel - Change path of markdown components for a package

Tags: laravel

I am developing a Package using Laravel 7, and in this package I will have emails.

I want to use markdown emails, so I published the views :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-mail
```

And I want these views to be embedded in my package, so I just copy `/resources/views/vendor/mail` to `/package/packageAuthor/packageName/resources/views/vendor/mail`.

But how can I have my app to load the components for my package ?

I know I can edit the config `mail.php` :

```
'markdown' => [
    'theme' => 'default',

    'paths' => [
        base_path('package/packageAuthor/packageName/resources/views/vendor/mail'),
    ],
],
```

But when I want to import the package in other Laravel Project, how can I make this project to use my components ? without modifying the config ?

1. Do I have to override the config of the application ?
2. Do I have to publish the views from my package ?
3. Do I have to use themes ?

I see this function : `loadComponentsFrom` in the `Markdown` class, but how can I use it ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok for now I use a super class, it seems to work :

```
<?php

namespace Lpa\Common\Illuminate;

use Illuminate\Container\Container;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Mail\Markdown;

class MailableLpa extends Mailable
{
    /**
     * Override buildMarkdownView() to define new components path
     *
     * @return array
     *
     * @throws \ReflectionException
     * @throws \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
     */
    protected function buildMarkdownView()
    {
        /** @var Markdown $markdown */
        $markdown = Container::getInstance()->make(Markdown::class);

        // use package resources path
        $markdown->loadComponentsFrom([
            __DIR__. '/../../resources/views/vendor/mail'
        ]);

        $data = $this->buildViewData();

        return [
            'html' => $markdown->render($this->markdown, $data),
            'text' => $this->buildMarkdownText($markdown, $data),
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks!